# Trying to make a handle

Tags: modeling

I want to make a handle like the picture;

[image]

The highlighted one is made from a path and the one behind it is made with extruding etc. The one made with the path looks the best but I'm very new to blender and I want to make sure that my poly count isn't too high.

I'm making an armoured vehicle and as you can imagine this is a tiny object compared to the vehicle. I can't make all the details with a lot of polys because that will kill the server that has to run the vehicle (or I think that's how it works?)

Is there an actual disadvantage/impact to having a lot of polys when you make something for a videogame? How heavy is the path-handle on polys? All it shows are the verts I used to make the path, not the amount of faces etc it used to fill it up.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the path; it probably won't be too hard on the game engine. The extruded one should also work, although I would make it out of simple rectangles to keep the poly count down, unless you need to see it up close.

That said, you probably don't even need a handle at all--you can just paint it into the texture on the side of the vehicle.

Comment: as far as I understand I have to convert everything to tris instead of polys as the game engine needs triangles, how do I do that for a path?

Comment: It doesn't even accept quads!? I would use the extruded version, then, although you can always convert the path to a mesh (Alt+C).

Comment: AFAIK all games need triangles but I can just convert that after :). Thanks for the help. Do you know by any chance how big the impact is on the amount of verts/faces/etc?

Comment: Well, you can see in Blender's top bar (the info panel) how many verts/faces/etc. you have. I'm surprised about the triangle thing, does it throw an error if you try to use quads? (Now, it might still triangulate them later, without telling you, when the game actually runs. But you shouldn't have to worry about that--Blender actually does the same thing.)

Comment: I'm far from getting it in the game so I don't know if it throws an error. I've learnt it online and from importing another vehicle from the game into Blender, it all has triangles.https://gyazo.com/ee589aeb23ce661304917538368b023c

Comment: So it's from a game in the first place? They may have done that themselves for some reason, but that doesn't mean you have to. What's that gyazo.com link?

Comment: It's from a modder who made another vehicle for the game and then made it open-source. The link is a picture of that vehicle.